# SQLiteDatabase Error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm currently trying to add data to the database but when I try to launch the application crashes and I get an error message saying that the table doesn't exist.

Here's the code where I create my database:

```
package com.example.android_ca2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
public static final String PEOPLE_TABLE_NAME = "people";
public static final String PEOPLE_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String PEOPLE_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String PEOPLE_COLUMN_AGE = "age";
public static final String PEOPLE_COLUMN_HEIGHT = "height";
public static final String PEOPLE_COLUMN_WEIGHT = "weight";


public DBHelper(Context context)
{
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  db.execSQL(
  "create table " + PEOPLE_TABLE_NAME +
  "(id integer primary key, name text,age text,height text, weight text)"
  );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PEOPLE_TABLE_NAME);
  onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertPerson  (String name, String age, String height, String weight)
{
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

  contentValues.put("name", name);
  contentValues.put("age", age);
  contentValues.put("height", height);  
  contentValues.put("weight", weight);

  db.insert("people", null, contentValues);
  return true;
}
public Cursor getData(int id){
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from people where id="+id+"", null );
  return res;
}
public int numberOfRows(){
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, PEOPLE_TABLE_NAME);
  return numRows;
}
public boolean updatePerson (Integer id, String name, String age, String height, String   weight)
{
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put("name", name);
  contentValues.put("phone", age);
  contentValues.put("email", height);
  contentValues.put("street", weight);

  db.update("people", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) }   );
  return true;
}

public Integer deletePerson (Integer id)
{
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  return db.delete("people", 
  "id = ? ", 
  new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllPeople()
{
  ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from " + PEOPLE_TABLE_NAME, null );
  res.moveToFirst();
  while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
  array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_COLUMN_NAME)));
  res.moveToNext();
  }
return array_list;
}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try incrementing the version number in the constructor call to `super` to force a delete/recreate?

Comment: I just cleared the app data and that did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting an error that says the table doesn't exist then it is pretty certain that the table you are trying to access is not in the database.

You most likely added the table at an earlier point in your apps life and have not since updated the database version so onUpgrade has never been called.

Increment the version number or uninstall the app so onCreate runs again.